# Akka http client timeouts are not applied

Tags: akka, akka-http

We are using akka http client for downloading files. And these connection & idle timeout props are set in config files:

```yaml
CONFIG_FORCE_app_file__dl_http_akka_http_host__connection__pool_client_connecting__timeout: 2s
CONFIG_FORCE_app_file__dl_http_akka_http_host__connection__pool_client_idle__timeout: 3s
```

These timeouts work in most of calls, but we have some instances in our logs which take a lot more time than the configured timeouts:

StreamTcpException (connect timeout):

```
Download failed in "51942"ms with reason "StreamTcpException".
error-msg: 
[Tcp command [Connect(file.example.com/<unresolved>:443,None,List(),Some(2 seconds),true)] failed 
because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(2 seconds) expired].
```

TcpIdleTimeoutException (idle timeout):

```
Download failed in in "39424"ms with reason "TcpIdleTimeoutException". 
error-msg: 
[TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection to [file.example.com/<unresolved>:80], 
no bytes passed in the last 3 seconds].
```

Is there anything we can check/do to fix the issue?

We are using `akka-http:10.2.0` & `akka:2.6.19`.

Comment: could you tell a bit more about your context? is it possible a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?